# pc power offs automatically on bios and windows 10 boot but not on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, bios

I am having problem in my pc where my pc automatically power offs without any warning. My pc is dual boot system with ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. Whenever I try to boot Windows 10 it power offs abruptly on Windows logo. When I tried bootable usb Windows 10 for clean install it also caused sudden power off on windows logo.

Above all this when I run diagnostics or setup utility or bios screen pc automatically poweroffs after about 10 seconds.

What could be the cause of this problem ? I check with Dell technical support that my bios version is upto date. I do not think its motherboard issue since ubuntu runs as normal on my pc. My pc is Dell Inspiron N5010

Comment: I can tell you its very likely a hardware problem and that its probably the power supply (specifically in the motherboard not the part you plugin) and therefor fried OR its because the system fan or temp sensor has failed. However the only thing you could do yourself unless you know how to take things apart is just try blowing compressed air in the vents. It may not be it but its the only thing you can do without taking it apart. If thats not it you should probably take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

most likely, overheating. Everything can be done yourself carefully, only neatly and slowly. Cleaning the fan, radiator. Replacement of thermal paste. If the thermal pads have dried - carefully remove them, drip a few drops of ethyl alcohol, knead and install into place. http://www.myfixguide.com/manual/dell-inspiron-n5010-disassembly-clean-up-cooling-fan/
Do not mix up the screws !!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried going into your computer and checking/re-seating any connections. It sounds to me like a power supply related issue, you may need to replace your power supply, or simply re-seat it